# Internet connection established over VPN on my router, but need to connect to University's network via VPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I'm forced by my student hostel (I do not know who our actual ISP is, the hostels in our city provide their own gigabit internet service) to connect via VPN, otherwise I can't establish an internet connection. It's configured in the router, so I don't have to log in every time on my PC.

My problem: I need to have a VPN connection to my University network to access files for my courses, but openconnect thinks otherwise:

```
POST https://example.com/

Attempting to connect to server [0000:000:000:0b0d::000]:000

Connected to [0000:000:000:0b0d::000]:000

SSL negotiation with example.com

SSL connection failure: The operation timed out

Failed to open HTTPS connection to example.com
```

It works in my friend's apartment who has a regular ISP provider though.

Comment: This might be a question for your University's IT support

Comment: Actually, connect to the VPN you are using for internet first, then connect to university.